# rust custom debug output for external object?

Tags: debugging, rust, formatting

I am debugging some code that depends on nalgebra. 3d Vectors in nalgebbra are 3x1 matrices, so when they are printed I get this:

```
        [
            [
                -1.5769595,
                76.86241,
                40.108894,
            ],
        ],
        [
            [
                -1.4947789,
                76.70875,
                39.909042,
            ],
        ],
        [
            [
                -1.5849781,
                76.93078,
                40.18302,
            ],
        ],
```

I am doing 3D modelling so 99.999999% of all my use cases are going to treat vectors and covectors as just vectors.

I'd love to change this printing to just be:
[x, y, z],

Which would be much more compact and infinitely times better for my use case. Is this doable?

Comment: Easy: Remove `#derive(Debug)` and `impl Debug` yourself.

Comment: It's on a foreign type, it;s on the nalgebra library so I don;t have direct control over the types traits and impls

Comment: You'll have to wrap it in something you do control, which could be as trivial as `X(Y)` and then [`impl AsRef`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html) to bridge to `self.0`. That'll make it a fairly transparent, near zero cost drop-in replacement. The only other alternative is to write a debug function you just call manually instead. The debug function is lower cost, but more programming work to use, as `{:?}` won't do the trick, so you can decide which approach works best for you.